# Dont create userRepository bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

Im beginer in Spring, Help please

Entity

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    protected User(){}
    public User(String name, String pass) {
        username = name;
        password = pass;
    }

}
```

Repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Controller:

```
  @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/users")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public class UserController {
        @Autowired
        UserRepository userRepository;

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public List<User> getUsers()
        {
            List<User> result = new ArrayList<User>();
            userRepository.findAll().forEach(result::add);
            return result;
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public User addUser(String username, String password, String password_confirm)
        {
            if (username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || password_confirm.isEmpty())
                return null;
            if (!password.equals(password_confirm))
                return null;
            return userRepository.save(new User(username, password));
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/add",method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView getUserForm()
        {
            return new ModelAndView("add");
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
        public void delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id)
        {
            userRepository.delete(id);
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public User getUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id)
        {
            return userRepository.findOne(id);
        }
    }
```

data Config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:hibernate.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories( "com.sergey.repository")
public class DataConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));


    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
            dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
            return dataSource;
        }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.sergey.entity");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emfb.setDataSource(dataSource());
        emfb.setPackagesToScan("com.sergey.entity");
        emfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        emfb.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return emfb;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

pom.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
>          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>
>     <groupId>springSecure</groupId>
>     <artifactId>springSecure</artifactId>
>     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>     <build>
>         <plugins>
>             <plugin>
>                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>                 <configuration>
>                     <source>1.6</source>
>                     <target>1.6</target>
>                 </configuration>
>             </plugin>
>         </plugins>
>     </build>
>
>     <properties>
>         <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
>         <spring.security.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
>         <hibernate-version>5.0.11.Final</hibernate-version>
>         <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
>     </properties>
>
>     <dependencies>
>         <!--Spring Framework-->
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
>             <version>${spring.version}</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
>             <version>${spring.version}</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
>             <version>${spring.version}</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
>             <version>${spring.version}</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <!--Spring Security-->
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
>             <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
>             <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
>             <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <!--Spring DB-->
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
>             <version>${spring.version}</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa
> ```
>
> -->
>               
>                   org.springframework.data
>                   spring-data-jpa
>                   1.10.2.RELEASE
>               
>               
>               
>                   org.springframework.data
>                   spring-data-commons-core
>                   1.4.0.RELEASE
>               
>               
>               
>                   org.hibernate
>                   hibernate-core
>                   ${hibernate-version}
>               
>               
>               
>                   jstl
>                   jstl
>                   1.2
>               
>               
>               
>                   javax.servlet
>                   javax.servlet-api
>                   3.0.1
>                   provided
>               
>               
>               
>                   com.fasterxml.jackson.core
>                   jackson-annotations
>                   2.8.1
>               
>               
>                   org.postgresql
>                   postgresql
>                   9.4.1211.jre7
>
> ```
>     </dependencies>
>
> </project>
> ```

Error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path
>   resource [com/sergey/config/DataConfig.class]: Ambiguous factory
>   method matches found in bean 'transactionManager' (hint: specify
>   index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type
>   ambiguities): [public
>   org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager
>   com.sergey.config.DataConfig.transactionManager(javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory),
>   public org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager
>   com.sergey.config.DataConfig.transactionManager(org.hibernate.SessionFactory)]
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:561)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1863)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> окт 29, 2016 3:33:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log

Comment: it is really obvious if you check a stacktrace and code you provided

Comment: where is the mistake?

Comment: you already have an answer below

Comment: why do you use `@NoRepositoryBean`? what is the purpose?

Comment: but the error is not lost

Comment: i remove annotation @NoRepositoryBean

Comment: does it located at `com.sergey.repository`? you have to update your post and remove annotation

Comment: yes, package com.sergey.repository;

Comment: is your application spring boot? if so does application know about your data config?

Comment: it is not spring boot

Comment: have you register in some way your data config in app context?

Comment: `@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com.sergey.config", "com.sergey.controller", "com.sergey.entity", "com.sergey.service"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
        return viewResolver;`

Comment: here `@ComponentScan({"com.sergey.config", "com.sergey.controller", "com.sergey.entity", "com.sergey.service"})` absents `com.sergey.repository`

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/sergey/config/DataConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource

Comment: What DB do you use? Have you provide a jdbc driver? Add to your post your `pom.xml` and `hibernate properties` and i need full stack of exception with `jpaVendorAdapter`

Comment: jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springSecure
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create

Comment: why do you add it here? add it to your post

Comment: now update post

Comment: now it is much more readable. not sure , but try to add `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
</dependency>` to your `pom.xml`

Comment: It helped, but new bug, please see

Comment: you have two transaction managers in your config - `PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager`,  `HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager`. not sure which one you need - just play with - comment one and leave other, if not help comment other, and uncomment first

Comment: runs every, now need to understand what is needed, thank you very much

Comment: np, you can close question if it is answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring repositories are implemented at runtime by Spring-JPA framework and @NoRepositoryBean should only be marked for the BaseRepositories which are used to provide some default behaviour to all sub-interfaces (if any).

The exception says that "No qualifying bean of type `[com.sergey.repository.UserRepository]`" found for dependency, this is because Spring container did not provide the implementation as it is marked with `@NoRepositoryBean`

In other words, you should NOT add `@NoRepositoryBean` annotation to the `UserRepository` as it is a concrete repository interface, which needs to be implemented by Spring-JPA framework (at runtime). So remove the annotation at the top and then `UserRepository` class becomes as follows:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Please refer the below documentation for more details:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: deleted and restarted the server/container ?

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository': No qualifying bean of type [com.sergey.repository.UserRepository] found for dependency [com.sergey.repository.UserRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)};

Comment: Some problem with the build, check the server lib/classes folder whether the latest class files are being generated or not